# copy matching files from a drive to a folder based on fodlername in powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a a bunch of language folders present in a directory under E:\Data\ like hu-hu, de-de etc.. on the other hand i have a bunch of file names in G:\ that contain the part of folder name for e.g.
amd64.de-de_OCR.cab,amd64.handwriting.de-de.cab

I need to copy all matching file names based on the foldername

for e.g. de-de should copy all matching files in G:\ i.e. both amd64.de-de_OCR.cab,amd64.handwriting.de-de.cab

This is the code i have so far but it is not copying over the files, and i am not sure how to proceed next, any help is appreciated.

```
$listfoldername = Get-ChildItem -Path "E:\Data" -Recurse -Directory -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Select-Object Name
$destfolder = Get-ChildItem -Path "E:\Data" -Recurse -Directory -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Select-Object FullName
$filename = Get-ChildItem -file G:\
if($filename -like $listfoldername)
{
Copy-Item -Path $filename -Destination $destfolder
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few issues with your code

1. The main issue with your code is that you are trying to use the `-like` operator to compare two objects (your object containing the directories you wish to move files to, and the object containing the files.

   - What you need to do is loop through each file and directory, one by one, to determine if the directory name (e.g. "hu-hu" is found in the filename (e.g. amd64.hu-hu_OCR.cab)
2. You'll want to use the wildcard indicator "*" with the `-like` operator (e.g. `"*hu-hu*"`)

This below code snippet should do the trick. I tested using the file and folder names you've provided.

"G:" contains the folders:

- `de-de`
- `hu-hu`
- `us-us` (note, I added this to make sure the code did not match this directory)

"E:\Data" contains the files

- `amd64.de-de_OCR.cab`
- `amd64.handwriting.de-de.cab`
- `amd64.handwritinghu-hu.cab`
- `amd64.hu-hu_OCR.cab`

```
$FileDirectory = "G:" # Change to "G:\", the trailing slash breaks syntax highlight on SO
$DataDirectory = "E:\Data"

$listfoldername = Get-ChildItem -Path "$DataDirectory" -Recurse -Directory -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Select-Object Name
$filename = Get-ChildItem -file "$FileDirectory"

#Loop through each file one at a time
foreach ($file in $filename) {
    # Then, loop through each folder one at a time
    foreach ($folder in $listfoldername) {
        # Set the current filename and listfoldername to variables for later -like operator
        $FileString = $file.Name
        $FolderString = $folder.Name
        # If the current file "is like" the current folder name
        if($FileString -like "*$FolderString*")
            {
                # Set the name of the current folder to a variable
                $DataFolder = $folder.Name
                Copy-Item -Path "$FileDirectory\$FileString" -Destination "$DataDirectory\$DataFolder"
            } else {
                Write-Output ("$FolderString pattern not found in $FileString")
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should start off by getting a list of possible language target folders. Then loop over the path where the files are, filtering their names to have at least the dash in it and next test if any of the language target folders matches the filename.

Something like this:

```
$langFolder = 'E:\Data'
$fileFolder = 'G:\'          #'# dummy comment to fix syntax highlighting in SO

# get a list of the language folders
# if the languages folder has multiple subdirectories to include, add -Recurse here
$targetFolders = Get-ChildItem -Path $langFolder -Directory

# get a list of FileInfo objects for the files in the G:\ path
# if you need to search subdirectories aswell, add -Recurse here
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $fileFolder -File -Filter '*-*.*'
foreach($file in $files) {
    # check if a language name matches the file name
    foreach($folder in $targetFolders) {
        if ($file.BaseName -like "*$($folder.Name)*") {
            # we have found a matching language target directory
            $file | Copy-Item -Destination $folder.FullName
            break  # exit this folder foreach loop and get on with the next file
        }
    }
}
```

P.S. If all the files are `.cab` files you could speed up by setting the Filter to `'*-*.cab'` in line `$files = Get-ChildItem ...`